# Iterating multidimensional hashtables in powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable, powershell-3.0

I have to iterate trought a multidimensional hashtable like:

```
$ou=@{
      class = @{
              value1 = @{
                       1= ""
                       }
              value2 = ""
              value3 = ""
              }
      }
```

All I need is a way to access every key of the hashtable (values1, value2, ...).
I already tried foreach and for loops but without success.
At first I used a foreach loop to iterarte trought the first hashtable:

```
foreach ($key in $a.keys){
    write-host $key.keys
}
```

But I struggle adding a second loop. Do I have to iterate the keys again? And why does $key.keys give me all the keys back and not one after the other?

Comment: _I already tried foreach and for loops but without success._ Can we see how?

Comment: At first place I did this:
`foreach ($key in $a.keys){
        $ouName = '{0}' -f $key, $a[Akey]
        New-ADOrganizationalUnit -Name "$ouName" -Path "DC=$DC, DC=$DCD" -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false
}`
But when I added a second loop (for the second "dimension") I used:
`foreach ($Bkey in $key.keys){}`
I guess that I have to irrerate throught something else than `$key.keys` but havn't figured out yet what....

Comment: Please place this in the question. Reading code in comments is the suck...

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "access every key"? You literally have access to every key right now. What do you want to do with them? Display their values? Show the entire tree structure? Manipulate them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
function keys ($h) { foreach ($k in $h.keys) { $k ; keys $h[$k] }}
```

will recurse through all the keys. Note that it recurses on the *value* of the hashtable element not the *key*. So in your comment example, you probably wanted to iterate over `$a[$key].key` not `$key.keys`in in the second-level loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed the `$a[$key].keys` solved it for me!

Comment: What do those variable names represent?